# Как взаимодействовать с динамическими элементами на сайте. Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Есть виджет (iframe) который состоит из 2 страниц. На первой странице пользователь выбирает товар, на второй заполняет контактные данные и отправляет форму (Вторая страница подгружается и заменяет первую после выбора товара).

Вопрос: как получить данные из формы (при отправке) если на момент загрузки jQuery самой формы (на 2 странице) нет в коде сайта?

Comment: "Как получить данные из формы ... если ... самой формы .. нет". Это как? Где код?

Comment: Через селекторы jQuery можно получить любой элемент и вытащить его значение, но без кода ничего не понять.